# How to save checkbox values?

Tags: checkbox

My website is basically a to-do list for my class, there's a checkbox next to each item and when you click them they strikethrough. It looks like this:

```
<span><input type="checkbox" OnClick='strikeIt(this)'> Text Here. </span>
```

Now, the point is I want that it saves the values (Done/not done) of the checkboxes for every different device that uses the page, so that when they come back, they still have checked the things they have done. How can I do this, I only now the basics of HTML, so any help would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

As for device-basisc you will have to use cookies.

EDIT:

here you have all information you needd for cookies via javascript http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Ok, but how do I make one, set it up, etc?